# Is it possible for Firebase Cloud Functions to receive http request from an extenal server, while on Blaze Plan?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been searching and haven't found whether it is possible for a firebase project using the Blaze Plan to receive http requests from an external server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have implemented [https functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), you can recieve https requests from external server, after you deploy the function you'll get url for each functions either from terminal or firebase console in **functions** section, check the [github repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/time-server) for sample